# How to fix "Program terminated with signal SIGFPE"

Tags: c++, c++11

The question is :-

Given an integer, for each digit that makes up the integer determine whether it is a divisor. Count the number of divisors occurring within the integer.

Complete the `findDigits` function in the editor below.

`findDigits` has the following parameter(s):

int n: the value to analyze

```
int findDigits(int n) {
   vector<int> digits;
   int temp = n;
   int result = 0;
   while(temp!=0){
       digits.push_back(temp%10);
       temp/=10;
   }
   for(int i=0 ; i<digits.size() ; i++){
       int s = digits[i];
       if(n % s == 0){
           result ++;
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

The error I got is :

```
Reading symbols from Solution...done.

[New LWP 769213]

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Core was generated by `./Solution'.

Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.

#0  0x0000000000401433 in findDigits (n=1012) at Solution.cpp:16

16          if(n % s == 0){

To enable execution of this file add

    add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py

line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".

To completely disable this security protection add

    set auto-load safe-path /

line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".

For more information about this security protection see the

"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:

    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

Comment: What if `s` is zero at `if(n % s == 0)`?

Comment: To add onto @user4581301's observation, that should happen if `n` has a 0 digit in it (ie: 102, 120, etc...)

Comment: Thanks @user4581301

Comment: Please use the title to quickly communicate the nature of your problem as specifically as you can, not "I have an error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   int findDigits(int n) {
   vector<int> digits;
   int temp = n;
   int result = 0;
   while(temp!=0){
       digits.push_back(temp%10);
       temp/=10;
   }
   for(int i=0 ; i<digits.size() ; i++){
       int s = digits[i];
         if(n % s == 0 && s != 0)
           result ++;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Its a Runtime Error the value of `s` might have been `0` at some point so you are facing these errors.